# snmpwalk: –c: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> –c)

Tags: ubuntu, snmp, snmpwalk

I am relatively new to snmp and am trying to test out snmp on a device with snmpwalk command. I am using it as such: `snmpwalk -v2c -c public <ip>`

and it returns and error of `–c: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> –c)`

I've tried removing the `-c public` option and it just gives an `Unknown Object Identifier <ip>`

The debian packages for snmp I have are `snmp snmp-mibs-downloader snmpd snmptrapd`

I have not seen much online about this specific error and from looking at examples and the docs I believe I am using the command correctly. Maybe there is some configuration or package I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I restarted the snmp service and using `-v 2c`